# Passing JavaScript to Session variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a variable to a php session variable, so I can access it later from other functions. I might have a totally approach, I'm not sure. What I want to do is to have my vaiable stored somewhere so I can access it anytime and anywhere within a session. 
This is what I have now:

```
$(".small-item-card .bookmark").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let el_id = $(this).attr("element-id");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/session.php',
            data: {el_id: el_id},
            success:function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

PHP - session.php

```
<?
session_start();

$element_id = (isset($_POST['el_id']) ? $_POST['el_id'] : "empty");

$_SESSION['element_ids'] = $element_id;

echo $_SESSION['element_ids'];

?>
```

When I open session.php page it prints "empty". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make sure you're passing the data using for example : `data: {el_id: "test"},`

Comment: make sure also that the session creation work statically like `$_SESSION['element_ids'] = "test"`.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I checked "data" with "test" - still not working. And session creation works statically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because when you open `session.php`, `(isset($_POST['el_id']) ? $_POST['el_id'] : "empty");` will run, changing `$_SESSION['element_ids']` to **empty**.

Your code is working as it should be. Try echoing `$_SESSION['element_ids']` to the main page instead, and you will see that it contains the right value. Try something like this for quick debugging, put it at the top of your main page. **AND** don't open `session.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo (isset($_SESSION['element_ids'])) ? $_SESSION['element_ids'] : 'not yet set';
?>
```

Comment: Accidentally caught this while checking for possible errors in `data: {el_id: el_id}`